# ImageMagic import tool fails to capture a maximized browser

Tags: imagemagick, x11, xserver

I am doing something quite simple:

```
 import -window root foo.png
```

This is supposed to capture the entire desktop - and it does... after a fashion. In fact, it captures everything except:

1. no desktop background - it remains black
2. it is "blind" to a maximized chrome. Unmaximizing it brings the contents into the screenshot
3. it displays black border around windows, which does not exist.

I am on

```
 CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
 X.Org X Server 1.19.3
 ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16
```

Standard Screenshot capture utility works correctly - I am trying to figure out if I can fix the import tool setup for our test runs.
[image: See pic includes a non-maximized browser but what's with the borders?]
[image: See the black background and invisible browser]

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using? Check with `identify -version`

Comment: Thanks Mark!  ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16

Comment: Mmmm, that's 4+ years old.... try updating if possible.

Comment: I think there's some recent security improvements that prevent screen captures. What your describing matches the feature behavior listed [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Screen_capture_is_not_available_with_usual_apps).